# Stripe: How to continue on residual trial period after switching the plan

Tags: stripe-payments

> Our product has 4 plans.
>
> (a) Free plan (Trial period = 14 days) (b) Starter   (Trial period =
>   14 days) (c) Pro (Trial period = 14 days) (d) Enterprise (Trial period
>   = 14 days)
>
> User is automatically signed with free plan with 14 days trial 
>   period. What I want is if the user switches to any plan before 14 
>   days trial, the residual trial should continue and payment should 
>   happen at the end of 14 days.
>
> Example: user logs in with free plan and on 3rd day switches to 
>   'starter' plan. The trail period of 12 days should continue and  user
>   should be charged only at the end of the 12 days.
>
> Right now as soon as user selects a paid plan, payment is getting 
>   triggered, I want the payment trigger to happen after 14 days 
>   collective trail period is done.
>
> Php code sample to modify subscription:
>
> ```
> stripe.Subscription.modify(subscription_id,
>                 cancel_at_period_end=False,
>                 items=[{
>                     'id': subscription['items']['data'][0].id,
>                     'plan': plan,
>                 }]
>             )
> ```

Answer (score 1):

When using plans with pre-defined trial period lengths, you would also need to include the [trial_from_plan](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-trial_from_plan) parameter. This will dictate the subscription be created using the trial period days from the existing plan. This parameter is defaulted to false so once the customer is switched to the paid plan, the trial period is not reciprocated from the plan, causing the immediate charge.

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't seem like [trial_from_plan](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-trial_from_plan) can't be used when using `trial_end`. Documentation doesn't seem to indicate how to continue a trial when a plan changes because it seems to be attached to the plan itself, not to the customer. It's probably best to store the `trial_end` timestamp on the database and use a webhook to set the trial period each time the user changes the plan.